# RXJS: returning nested observables

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs

I'm trying to return a UserDetail object which consists of a User and Results, User is retrieved via the accessToken of Account (all retrieved via individual async calls). At the moment I'm stuck at figuring out how I can return this UserDetail object when I navigate to the detailcomponent  (I know it is not possible to literally return the object since the call is async, but I need to use this object in my component).

The code below gives me the following error:

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'

I tried using pipes and maps since I've read this is how I should 'return' async calls to the component calling the function. The component is then supposed to handle the subscription, but I can't even get that far without creating errors.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserResolver implements Resolve<UserDetails> {
  constructor(
    private as: AccountService,
    private rs: ResultService,
    private auth: AuthService
  ) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<UserDetails> {
    return this.as.getAccount(route.params['id']).pipe(
      map((acc: Account) => {
        this.as.getUserDetails(acc.access_token).pipe(
          map((user: User) => {
            if (user != null) {
              this.rs.getResults(this.auth.token).pipe(
                map((res: Result[]) => {
                  const ud: UserDetails = {
                    user,
                    results: res.filter(x => x.userId === acc.uid)
                  };
                  return of(ud);
                })
              );
            }
          })
        );
      })
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `switchMap` instead of `map`. `map` simply transforms one value into another, whereas `switchMap` allows you to switch to another observable.

Without knowing too much about what's going on, I think you want something like this:

```js
let user: User;
let account: Account;
return this.as.getAccount(route.params['id']).pipe(
  tap((acc: Account) => account = account),
  switchMap((acc: Account) => this.as.getUserDetails(acc.access_token)),
  // this filter will stop the next steps from running if the user is null
  // it will also mean a value isn't emitted
  // if you want to emit a null, you will need to modify the pipe
  filter((u: User) => u !== null),
  tap((u: User) => user = u),
  switchMap((u: User) => this.rs.getResults(this.auth.token))
  map((res: Result[]) => {
    const ud: UserDetails = {
      user,
      results: res.filter(x => x.userId === account.uid)
    };
    return ud;
  })
);
```

Notice how it's no longer indented like yours, but a sequence of pipe operators. Whenever you want to switch to a new observable, use `switchMap` or `concatMap`. We are only using `map` to map the result of the last observable to the value that we want to return from the function.

Whenever state needs to be saved out of the middle of a pipe, I am using tap to assign it to a variable.

Also, you are making (possibly) redundant calls to `this.rs.getResults(this.auth.token)`. The call doesn't change based on the what the `id` param is, so you could just fetch once, and read from a cache on subsequent calls.

Edit: `concatMap` is also an option. They are slightly different. Both are sufficient for the purposes of this answer - I'm not going to make assumptions about your use case.

Comment: OP must be using `concatMap` instead of `switchMap` as the nested observables are dependent on the subscription values of the outer ones.

Comment: Please, tell me why `switchMap` won't work here. In a stackblitz demo, preferably

Comment: `switchMap` will get you the expected result here but it might induce a wrong conception about `switchMap` for the OP. `switchMap` is generally used when you want to cancel the previous ongoing observable and subscribe to the new one when a new value is available. In this case, this is not needed and the simple `concatMap` will do the trick.

Comment: So `switchMap` will work here? OK. Is it functionally equivalent to `concatMap` here? Yes. I stated in my question that "`switchMap` allows you to switch to another observable" - I didn't say it was the **only** way.

Comment: Your original comment - "OP must be using concatMap instead of switchMap as the nested observables are dependent on the subscription values of the outer ones.". The use of "must" here suggests that `switchMap` is wrong and that `concatMap` is the *only* solution. You've now changed from "must" to just stating an assumption that `concatMap` is **definitely** the right choice here.

Comment: My bad, I didn't mean that way. As you said, switchMap works in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208655/discussion-between-shravan-and-kurt-hamilton).

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should avoid nested piping when possible so it is maintainable.
Instead combine Observables.

But for your problem: just remove "of(ud)" and then just return ud in your last map.

**Tipp for maintainability:**

I see you have one call wich don't need do be resolved in order.

```js
const userDetails$: Observable<Userdetails> = this.rs.getResults(this.auth.token)
                                         .pipe(map((res: Result[]) => {
                                             const ud: UserDetails = {
                                             user,
                                             results: res.filter(x => x.userId === acc.uid)
                                             };
                                              return ud;
                                             });

const userCheck$: Observable<User> = this.as.getAccount(route.params['id'])
                                     .pipe(map((acc: Account) => 
                                     this.as.getUserDetails(acc.access_token));

// Only when both values are available those observables will be ziped. 
// Only one subscription is needed on hte returned Obersvable 

return zip(userDetails$,userCheck$).pipe(map(([userDetails,user])) => {
                                   if (user != null) {
                                      return userDetails
                                  }else{
                                      // should probably emit a error
                                  }));
```

Comment: I need the user from userCheck$ to create the userDetails thought, but I assume the logic stays the same and I should just move the code a bit around, right?