# Rxjs call another subscription in pipe and change a varible from root subscription in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Using another subscription,  I want to set a property which comes from a root subscription.

So I have a subscription like this:

```
this.repository.getData(`api/cards/list`)
.subscribe(
  res => {
    this.data = res as EmployeeCard[];
  }
);
```

My EmployeeCard model like this:

```
export class EmployeeCard {
    id: number;
    employeeId: number;
    employeeFullName: string;
    companyId: number;
    cardId: number;
    cardNumber: string;
    currentSpendingLimit: string;
    limitResetDate: Date;
    cardUsageStatu: boolean;
    cardActiveDays: string;
    balance:string;
}
```

So I have to get `balance` from another api request.This request needs card `barcode` value. I can get the `barcode` with calling another request that returns card informations.Card request should be call with `cardId` value which returns with in `EmployeeCard` model.

So my new subscription should be like this:

```
this.repository.getData(`api/cards/list`)
.pipe(
    //get card information with cardId (needs another request using EmployeeCard cardId property)
    //get balance using card barcode  (needs another http request with using barcode)
    //set employeecard balance propery
    //return employeecard model's balance to subscription
  )
.subscribe(
  res => {
    this.data = res as EmployeeCard[];
  }
);
```

How can I do this with Rxjs?

Thanks

Comment: SwitchMap operator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RXJS: returning nested observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60436143/rxjs-returning-nested-observables)

Comment: @KurtHamilton No it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `switchMap` with selector function argument.

```js
function getData() {
  getEmpData()
    .pipe(
      switchMap(
        emp => getBalanlanceInfo(emp.cardId),
        (emp, balanceInfo) => {
          /**
           * Selector function variation of switchMap
           * perform logic with both source and inner observable values
           */
          emp.balance = balanceInfo.balance;
          return emp;
        }
      )
    )
    .subscribe(emp => {
      console.log(emp);
      // Perform your logic here
    });
}
```

You can find the complete example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-edjhxj) in Stackblitz. More on switchMap can be found [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-switchmap-operator/).

Comment: just an FYI on the selector function. I was a fan of it, but the RXJS team has deprecated it an reintroduced it more than once. Future proof yourself from their whims and use an inner map function

Comment: I don't see it as deprecated in [official docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap#overloads) and I have been using it for more than an year. Moreover, there are more than 1 way to solve an problem and this one seems more elegant to me and easier to read than a inner map.

Comment: rxjs 6.0.0 release notes: `switchMap|switchMapTo: switchMap and switchMapTo no longer take resultSelector arguments, to get the same functionality use switchMap and map in combination` ... they (quietly) reintroduced it at some point recently. it's nicer code but they tend to play it fast and loose with breaking changes. Trying to save you the hassle I went through migrating an entire app that made heavy use of the result selctor.

Comment: Okay but I'm using this variation from the day I read this [article](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-switchmap-operator/) which was posted on April 2019. The changelog you have shared is from 2018. So it's been there for almost an year now.

Comment: that article was written 4 years ago pre rxjs 5 and still uses that much older syntax. it was updated in april 2019.  the result selector existed for years and was deprecated in v6, and then was reintroduced with no explanation or announcement at some point roughly a year ago.  they have given no indication if this is merely a backwards compatability thing or if it's here to stay.  It could be removed entirely in v7 when they do away with the last of rxjs-compat... Do as you will, but I'd avoid it. rxjs guidance recommends inner map function still

Answer (score 3):

SwitchMap use case (possibly with inner Map?)

```
.pipe(
  switchMap(card => this.getOtherData(card.cardId).pipe(
    map(otherData => ({...card, ...otherData})) // or whatever map function
  )
)
```